# How to efficiently organise all object in a large space

Tags: collision-detection, scene-graph, octree

I've just about started with a project I've had in mind for ages. I don't quite know how to start such big projects (bigger than Pong, anyway), so I thought I would get started by making a basic organization.

Now, in games like Freelancer and X feature large, open spaces. I ma aware that these have to be organised, to ensure collision testing don't happen continuously anywhere but only where the player can see it.

I thought first about a general scene graph, I am familiar with those, but it would just have almost all objects directly in the root node. The next idea was a Quad/Octree, but the objects are not quite static, and I don't know if it would make sense if you have to change the tree's organisation every second frame.

So, how is this done in real games? I'm using C# with XNA, if that matters, and would like to run the game on the XBox as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the minimal information in the question, there is no general answer to that.

Except:  *Real* games use engines that implement features as scene-graphs and proper data structures for collsion-detection and -optimizations, rendering, network, input, serializing and much more.

The idea is to write a game, not an engine.

[Unity3D](http://unity3d.com/) is such an engine for C#.

Comment: Would the Blender Engine help me there, too? Unity looks nice, but are they good for a game like Freelancer?

Comment: AFAIK Blender only supports python as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_game_engines)

Comment: I don't know freelancer, but [here](http://unity3d.com/gallery/game-list) is a list of games made with Unity, that will give you an idea. A video with a spacecraft-like-game called Zero-Chance and made with Unity can be seen [here](http://zerochance.luftensteiner.org/media1.html)